# How do you read successive lines of linefeed-delimited text using a BlobstoreInputStream?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, io, inputstream

I would like to read a line of text at a time from the Blobstore using a [**BlobstoreInputStream**](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreInputStream.html) and process the text

```
123,ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,123,456,789,123\r\n
```

But the BlobstoreInputStream `read` methods don't offer the option to read successive chunks of delimited data based on a delimiter (`\r\n` in this case).

Is there a way to programmatically use one of the available `read` methods to do this:

```
public int read() throws java.io.IOException

public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws java.io.IOException
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the BlobstoreInputStream extend the Stream interface? If it does you could pass it into the constructor of a new Scanner, or a BufferedInputReader class, those each have a ReadLine() method or something similar.

I personally like the Scanner class because the conventional while loop for that is

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
String s = scanner.NextLine();
....
}
```